# Disabling system calls in C++

Tags: c++, gcc

Is it possible to disable [system calls](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) when compiling C++ code? And if it is, how would I do that?

And to extend this question a bit. I wish to make program to not be able to interact with operating system, except for file reading and writing. Is it possible to do this?

EDIT: With not be able to interact with OS, I mean to not be able to change anything in OS, like creating, editing or deleting something. My main concern is system calls, which would almost in all cases be intended to be harmful.

This is for grading programs, where I would be running other people code. The programs would usually solve various algorithmic problems, so there is no need for very advanced features. Basic (more or less) STL usage and classic code. There would be no external libraries (like Boost or anything like that) or multiple files.

Comment: Is this for grading, for example?

Comment: But then the program could do nothing at all; each process has an environment, a current directory, heap and stack memory, dynamic links to libraries etc.  If you cut it off from the O/S then it cannot exist.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Nonsense. You can disable system calls without pretending to the application that the entire OS doesn't exist. Just look at [geordi](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/geordi/), which does precisely this.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I'm aware of this :D I updated question a bit.

Comment: @enoyhs: You should ask for that instead. :) [Ask for the goal, not the step you perceive.](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal) Anyway, the first thing that comes to mind is the idea of running the program in a virtual machine. Or failing the students instantly if they foobar your machine.

Comment: @trojanfoe: isn't most of that given to the program before it starts running its own code? - exceptions being heap which requires `sbreak()`, and `dlopen()` which is far less common than load-time shared-library resolution.  Programs can still do a bit of maths, process some data files, spit out some results to stdout or file....

Comment: Calls to the system() funcation and system calls are really different beasts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible.

Take a look at the source code for [geordi](https://github.com/Eelis/geordi) to see how it does it. Geordi is an IRC bot that compiles, links and runs C++ code under an environment where most system calls are disabled.

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm looking for. Was hoping for easier solution, like passing an option to compiler, but this will solve few more issues too.
Thanks a lot :) Now I just need to get a hang of haskell :D

Answer (score 1):

```
#define system NO_SYSTEM_CALL
```

If you are ok with macros to generate errors for compilation purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could use any combination of the following:

- create your own library with a dummy function called `system` and link it with the student code (assuming you control the build steps)
- grep the source code (though preprocessing hacks could get around that)
- run the built binaries under an unprivileged user id, after chroot etc.
- use a virtual machine
- invoke the compiler with `-Dsystem=` (though the student could `#undef`)
- (maybe - have to check the end-user agreement) upload their source to ideone or similar and let their security handle such issues

Answer (score 0):

An program can always invoke system calls, at leased under *nix it can. You could however take a look at SELinux, Apparmor, GRsec this are kernel safeguards which can block certain system calls for an application.